# Facebook login responce not return email address

Tags: facebook, asp.net-mvc-3, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I am using facebook login in mvc3 project.I am try to fetch user email address. Here is my code:-

```
function getFaceBook() {
    FB.init({
        appId: 'xxxx', // App ID
        channelUrl: '//' + window.location.hostname + '/channel', // Path to your Channel File
        status: true, // check login status
        cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml: true,

    });
    FB.login(function (response) {

        FB.api('/me', function (response) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(response));
            alert(response.email)
            var Profile = "http://graph.facebook.com/" + response.id + "/picture";
            });
    });
```

All is working fine. But responce always return email undefine.Before last week it was working fine.
Can anyone tell me what i miss. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have the permissions to fetch the email of the user?

Comment: hi @Sahil yes i have a permission for this.

Comment: But I cant see that in your code. Check out my answer to see how to set perms

Comment: hi @Sahil thanks i was forgot. Now i use { perms: 'email' }) its working

Comment: Your code is not defensive, use what i mentioned in my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
FB.login(function (response) {
    if(response.authResponse)
    {
      FB.api('/me', function (response) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(response));
        alert(response.email)
        var Profile = "http://graph.facebook.com/" + response.id + "/picture";
        });
    }
    else
    {
        // not authorize
    }
},{scope: 'email'});
```